# Toggle div animation auto height

Tags: css, reactjs, animation

This code works great when I close the div and the div should get smaller, but the animation does not work when I am trying to open the div. Why is that, and how can I make that work?

```
const Container = styled.div`
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  max-height: ${props => (props.open ? '500px' : '20px')};
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: max-height 1s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  cursor: pointer;
`;
```

I would like to have auto height, but I read that you could set max-height to a larger height than you expect your div to contain. The downside with that is when you have animation time to 1s, the animation will use 1s to animate the max-height even though the height is smaller than the max height.

Comment: Can you provide a codesandbox link for this ?

Comment: Is the `Container` supposed to be 20px in height when not "open"? I mean, suppose that inside the container there is a paragraph 5 lines longs: will the overflowing lines cut hidden, or the content of the `Containe`r should ALWAYS have auto-height? If that's the case, I think `react-transition-group` could help (I can also build you a codepen if you explain me correctly what you want to achieve)

Comment: @MatteoGesmundo , yes that would be very nice if you did! Thank you in advance. Ideally I would want my height for "not open" to be auto, and when it is "open" I would like it to be auto as well.

Comment: So, just to be sure, in the beginning, the toggle is "close", meaning it's few pixel with the write, for example "Spoiler"; then, when you click it, the text inside it changes, it becames something longer, thus the toggle height increases, and you want the increasment animated.. Got it right?

Comment: @MatteoGesmundo, yes that seems to be right!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late response, animation on `height='auto'` it's very "boring" :P So, if you want the Toggle write to remain always visible, I suggest you to look at already existing Component, e.g. → https://springload.github.io/react-accessible-accordion/

There are plenty of them, and you can find them with keywords such as `react toggle`, `react accordion` and `react slidedown` ( or a combination of those :) )

Instead, if you wanto that the Toggle write hides while the long text appear, then I wrote you a Component (it's more an idea that you can improve, but I think it does what you asked already) → https://codepen.io/Gesma94/pen/MLxdbR

The idea is pretty easy, and can be seen in this algorithm:

1. The `Toggle` Component is constructed with `isOpen` property set to `true`, thus it renders the long text.
2. In `componentDidMount`, it is saved the height required by the long text in the state property `fullOpenHeight`, and the `isOpen` property is set to `false`.
3. Since in `componentDidMount` I've updated the state, the Toggle has been rendered with the short text and `componentDidUpdate` has been called. In that, Since `checkInitialHeights`, we save in the state of the Component the height of the Component with the short text, and set te `checkInitialHeights` property to `false`.
4. The Component is once again re-rendered and now it's ready to be used. Notice that I also use `closeHeight` and `openHeight` properties to have a nice feedback if you click again on the Toggle before it's closed/opened completely.

Hope it helps! Here also the fiddle.

```js
const animation = (isOpen, closeHeight, openHeight, fullCloseHeight, fullOpenHeight) => {
  if (isOpen && closeHeight !== null && openHeight !== null) {
    return `${slideDown(closeHeight, fullOpenHeight)} 1s linear`;
  }

  if (!isOpen && closeHeight !== null && openHeight !== null) {
    return `${slideUp(fullCloseHeight, openHeight)} 1s linear`;
  }

  return "";
}

const slideDown = (closeHeight, openHeight) => styled.keyframes `
    0% { height: ${closeHeight}px }
    0.1% { height: ${closeHeight}px }
    100% { height: ${openHeight}px }
`;

const slideUp = (closeHeight, openHeight) => styled.keyframes `
    0% { height: ${openHeight}px }
    0.1% { height: ${openHeight}px }
    100% { height: ${closeHeight}px }
`;

const Container = styled.default.div `
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation : ${props => animation(props.toggleState.isOpen, props.toggleState.closeHeight, props.toggleState.openHeight, props.toggleState.fullCloseHeight, props.toggleState.fullOpenHeight)}
    overflow: hidden;
`;

class Toggle extends React.Component {
  toggleDOM;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isOpen: true,
      checkInitialHeights: true,
      closeHeight: null,
      openHeight: null,
      fullCloseHeight: null,
      fullOpenHeight: null
    };
    this.toggleDOM = React.createRef();
  }

  handleToggle = (e) => {
    const {
      isOpen
    } = this.state;
    const currHeight = this.toggleDOM.current.getBoundingClientRect().height;

    if (!isOpen) {
      this.setState({
        isOpen: true,
        closeHeight: currHeight
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        isOpen: false,
        openHeight: currHeight
      });
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const toggleDOM = this.toggleDOM.current;
    const fullOpenHeight = toggleDOM.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    this.setState({
      fullOpenHeight,
      isOpen: false
    });
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const toggleDOM = this.toggleDOM.current;
    const {
      isOpen,
      closeHeight,
      openHeight,
      checkInitialHeights
    } = this.state;

    if (checkInitialHeights) {
      const fullCloseHeight = toggleDOM.getBoundingClientRect().height;
      this.setState({
        fullCloseHeight,
        checkInitialHeights: false
      });
      return;
    }

    if (isOpen && openHeight === null) {
      const newOpenHeight = this.toggleDOM.current.getBoundingClientRect().height;
      this.setState({
        openHeight: newOpenHeight
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return ( <
      Container innerRef = {
        this.toggleDOM
      }
      onClick = {
        this.handleToggle
      }
      toggleState = {
        this.state
      } > {
        this.state.isOpen ?
        this.props.children :
          this.props.title
      } <
      /Container>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isToggleOpen: false
    };
  }

  handleToggle = (e) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isToggleOpen: !prevState.isToggleOpen
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return ( <
      Toggle title = "Spoiler" >
      <
      p >
      Lorem Ipsum < br / >
      Lorem Ipsum < br / >
      Lorem Ipsum < br / >
      Lorem Ipsum < br / >
      Lorem Ipsum < br / >
      Lorem Ipsum < br / >
      Lorem Ipsum < br / >
      Lorem Ipsum < br / >
      <
      /p> <
      /Toggle>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/styled-components/3.4.10/styled-components.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```